# Activitylog PS - Event initiated by

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-log-analytics, oms

I created multiple script to identify who started or stopped a Vm using the activity log but unable to get the results - the script just executes without an output

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit

```
Get-AzureRmLog -StartTime 2018-10-01T10:30 -EndTime 2018-10-12T11:30
 -ResourceId /subscriptions/S1sub/resourceGroups/SamRG/providers/microsoft.compute/test
 -DetailedOutput -Maxrecord 100 -InformationAction stop     

Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceGroup samitrg -StartTime 2018-10-01T10:30
  -EndTime 2018-10-12T11:30 | Select-Object level,eventtimestamp,caller,ID,resourcegroupname,Authorization,scope |
  Export-Csv -Path c:\abc.csv

Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceGroup samitrg -StartTime 2018-10-01T10:30
    -EndTime 2018-10-12T11:30 | Where-Object OperationName -EQ Microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/deallocate/action
```

Comment: Any update? Could it solve your issue?

Comment: @Joy wang: Thank you for your response. I tried your script but it doesnot prvoide an output. It skips to the next line - Am I doing something wrong

`
$start = Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceId /subscriptions/<SUBID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/microsoft.compute/<VMNAME> | Where-Object { $_.Authorization.Action -eq "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action"} 
$start | Select-Object level,eventtimestamp,caller,ID,resourcegroupname,Authorization,scope`

Comment: I think it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command below, add the extra parameters you need, like `-StartTime`,`-EndTime`,etc,  it will work fine.

Start a VM:

```
$start = Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceId "<ResourceId>" | Where-Object { $_.Authorization.Action -eq "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action"} 
$start | Select-Object level,eventtimestamp,caller,ID,resourcegroupname,Authorization,scope
```

[image]

Stop a VM:

```
$stop = Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceId "<ResourceId>" | Where-Object { $_.Authorization.Action -eq "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action"} 
$stop | Select-Object level,eventtimestamp,caller,ID,resourcegroupname,Authorization,scope
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

START

```
Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceID /subscriptions/<SUBID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<VMName> -StartTime 2018-10-16T21:30 -EndTime 2018-10-16T21:50 -MaxRecord 20 | Where-Object { $_.Authorization.Action -eq "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action"} | Select-Object level,eventtimestamp,caller,ID,resourcegroupname,Authorization | Format-table -wrap -AutoSize -Property level,eventtimestamp,caller,resourcegroupname,ID -groupby Authorization
```

STOP

```
Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceID /subscriptions/<SUBID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<VMName> -StartTime 2018-10-16T21:30 -EndTime 2018-10-16T21:45 -MaxRecord 20 | Where-Object { $_.Authorization.Action -eq "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action"} | Select-Object level,eventtimestamp,caller,ID,resourcegroupname,Authorization | Format-table -wrap -AutoSize -Property level,eventtimestamp,caller,resourcegroupname,ID -groupby Authorization
```

Hope this helps everyone :)